# Laravel VentureCraft/revisionable error migration table

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, revisionable

I have a problem with install VentureCraft/revisionable in Laravel.
When I trying use this command:

```
php artisan migrate --package=venturecraft/revisionable
```

Artisan returned error:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException] The "--package"
>   does not exist.

I using Laravel version 5.2

Comment: I humbly request that you change the marked answer to @Steve's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you can migrate by:

```
php artisan migrate --path=vendor/venturecraft/revisionable/src/migrations
```

Comment: Yes, but does it scale? No. Any new installations of your project (aka, production servers, not your development machine) will have to run this migration _every_ time you create one. And, you have to take this into consideration _every_ time you do a `migrate:refresh`. Just to run the migration, this works fine, which is why I'm not down-voting, but I am up-voting @Steve 's answer, which should be the marked answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `--package` syntax was only available in Laravel 4. It seems like this package has old documentation based off that release.

You'll need to go into the `vendor/venturecraft/revisionable/migrations` folder and copy the migration and insert it in your `database/migrations` folder.

Then run the command `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: Although this is slightly more hacky, in the long run, this is a far better solution.